# jqplot centering month between ticks

Tags: jqplot

Pretty straightforward question. I  have a jqplotchart that looks like this:

[image]

and I want it to look like this (check x-axis): > this is a photoshopped image :)

[image]

So, I want the tick line to be at the first of the month, but id' like the label centered between the first of each month. How could i accomplish this? I tried using the CanvasAxisTickRenderer, but the best thing I could come up with was the prefix option (adding blank spaces), which places the month 'may' out of the canvas.

my current jqplot code for the xaxis looks like this:

```
            xaxis:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions:{
                    formatString:'%B',
                    showMark: false,
                    labelPosition: 'start',
                    fontFamily: 'helvetica, sans-serif',
                    fontSize: '8pt',
                    labelPosition: 'middle',
                },
                tickInterval: 'month',                  
                 min:'<?php echo date("Y");?>-01-01',
                 max:'<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>'
            },
```

thanks for your suggestions!

edit: important to mention: this is a dynamic generated chart, so hard coded labels are not an option I think.

Comment: You have the parameter `labelPosition` defined twice. Try to play with others options: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-canvasAxisTickRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer.labelPosition

Answer (score 0):

I use this technique, that ways it plots the graph and also centers the labels as you need.
I know this might not suit you but you can give it a shot.

```
xaxis: {
         show: true,
         label: "Date/Time",
         showLabel: false,
         showTicks: true,
         renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
       }
```